# Out of votes - Change message?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When trying to approve tag wiki edits I'm presented with the following text:

> Out of votes - you may not vote on this user any more today.

The text is misleading in that it makes me think that I may be able to approve another proposed tag wiki with a different author. However, this is not the case.

Why not simply let the text say:

> Out of votes

Thanks for considering this.

Answer (score 11):

From my understanding there are 3 out-of-votes scenarios:

- Out of Tag-Wiki votes
- out of per-user votes
- and out of daily limit votes.

They should all be clearly labeled.

Currently the last two notify you correctly.  The first one shares a message with the second one.

Comment: Be sure to have a look at my answer, stuff went a bit pear shape somewhere along the line.

Comment: @Waffles, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

I added all sorts of weird and wonderful protection to the suggested edit system.

The intention was always to have 2 **strong** bits of protections:

1. Cap the number of total votes you may make per day. (currently set at 30)
2. Cap the amount of voting a user can do on any individual's suggestions. (set at the theoretic value of 5 )

Theoretic ... I said ... I bet you were wondering why.

The theory is that if Bill starts flooding the suggestion queue with **tons** of suggestions we want to "balance out the voting". We do not want "Fred" to be the only person approving or declining Bill's edits. So we set a hard limit. Fred can only vote on 5 suggestions by Bill per day.

---

However, somewhere along the line I checked in an implementation that acts very differently to the desired behavior.

I performed the checking on the post owner instead of the suggestion owner. In practice this had a very undesired effect, the culmination of which is this bug.

All tag wikis have the same owner, the community user. The broken check was ensuring that you can only vote on 5 tag wikis a day.

Further more, in reality a large distribution of posts are edited. It is unlikely that there will ever be 40 edits on Jon Skeet's post in the queue at any point in time. So the check was never really triggering for non tag wiki approvals.

---

In retrospect I am not convinced we need the second throttle. Votes are limited, the only time you will have a "vote binge" on any one suggestor is if they decide to flood the queue. Flooding the queue is bad, and I do not mind if people can help out as quickly as possible in such a case, even if vote variety suffers.

For now I have commented out the check, discussing with Jeff removing check (2) on a permanent basis. (keep in mind check 2 has **never** been in place and we are not seeing any issues around this)

Comment: check 2 needs to go back in immediately; otherwise it is trivial to set up two accounts that do nothing but propose edits, and accept them for instant +2 rep per click. (particularly on other SE 2.0 sites, though SO does require 2 approvers..)

Comment: @Jeff ... not following ... you create 2 accounts ... reach 2k rep on one of them ... then go and suggest a ton of edits on your sock puppet account and approve 30 of them.... 1) how does this differ to simply editing stuff? its just as auditable. 2) what do we lose out here, sock puppet is capped at 1k rep from suggested edits ... though the reality is that nobody will ever reach that

Comment: I suppose; it's probably more effective to upvote the sockpuppets than approve edits, but it depends how closely we are watching that. I don't think we're really watching it at all, at the moment.. (also, the at name mention was not necessary, when the owner comments and there is only 1 other person talking, it automatically notifies that person on the basis of, well, who the hell ELSE could you have been talking to?)